# How to detect keystrokes?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, keys

I have a script running always at the background. Inside that script I have to write the codes to detect keystrokes, and once a particular keystroke is detected, the rest of the script must be executed. How can I do this?

I have tried the `showkey` command but failed to add that to my script.

Comment: Please comment if I should supply any additional information.

Comment: So, is this a bash script that you want to run in the background and you want to trap some keystrokes while continuing to use bash shell commands ?

Comment: @AnonymousPlatypus: Any feed-back on the above comment?

Comment: Exactly its is! ;)

Answer (score 2):

you can read the keystrokes by the read command for this use the following bash script

```
#! /bin/bash
read -s -n 1 key # -s: do not echo input character. -n 1: read only 1 character (separate with space)
if [[ "$key" == "your key" ]];then
    #your script here
fi
```

you can experiment with the read command and some bash scripts

Comment: This might be useful. Will try this and get back to you :)

Comment: Note this only works for keys that emit one byte (letters, numbers, space, etc). Things like arrow keys, pgup, esc, etc. won't work with this.